# Give a condition to auto check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

is there a way to do in javascript such that if I check a few checkboxes as a condition, one of the checkbox will be check. Currently here's my logic for the codes but it cant work.

```
$(document).ready( function a()
{
   if (  $('#condition1' && $('#condition2').is(':checked'))
    {
       $('#checkbox1').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Also, is it possible to put a class in the checkbox to do the check function instead of id?

Comment: i believe you want single checkbox selection in group of checkboxes.right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script is executed on document ready. After the execution is won't react to any action you take. In order to accomplish what you want, you need to run the script every time a check box is clicked.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if ( $('#condition1').is(':checked') && $('#condition2').is(':checked')){
       $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
       $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/CaZ7j

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your need to use a [change handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $checks = $('#condition1, #condition2').change(function () {
        $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', $checks.is(':checked'));
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9mne7/)

Comment: hi! is it possible to set it like $('#condition1 && #condition2').change
cause i tried this way it cant work.

Comment: no... may I ask why you want another way when this works fine